# How to access a variable outside of a nested for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a JS function with for loops. Inside the nested for loops, `str` element prints all of the intended elements. But, outside it doesn't print all of it. I would appreciate any help. Here is my code:

```
function getResearchersFullName(allDataJson){
    var str = [];
    var myarr = [];
    var c = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < allDataJson.length; i++){

        myarr[i] = allDataJson[i].Researchers.split(", ");

        for(var j = 0; j < myarr[i].length; j++){
            str[c] =  myarr[i][j];
            //console.log(str[c]); //prints as expected
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

I am trying to use the returned value as follows but it only prints one of the str values.

```
var fullnames = getResearchersFullName(allDataJson);

        for(var i = 0; i <fullnames.length; i++){
                console.log(fullnames[i]); //returns only 1 object

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code never increments `c`. The only element of `str` that's ever modified is element 0.

Use `str.push(myarr[i][j]);` and you won't need `c` at all.